# In angular ui-grid how to include footer row when exporting to pdf

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I am using ui-grid in my project where I have an added roe aggregated average row which reflects the average of the value of that column in the grid. Now I have implemented the Export to PDF option, but when exporting the grid doesn't include the footer row which reflects the average value. I looked into http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/api/ui.grid.exporter.api:GridOptions and tried as mentioned there:

```
gridOptions.exporterPdfCustomFormatter = function ( docDefinition ) {
  docDefinition.styles.footerStyle = { bold: true, fontSize: 10 };
  return docDefinition;
}

gridOptions.exporterPdfFooter = { text: 'My footer', style: 'footerStyle' }
```

or

```
gridOptions.exporterPdfFooter = 'My Footer';
```

or

```
gridOptions.exporterPdfFooter = {
  columns: [
    'Left part',
    { text: 'Right part', alignment: 'right' }
  ]
};
```

Seems like these options do not work or I am doing it wrong. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way I was able to figure it out.

Create a footer method

```
$scope.getFooterValue = function(i){
    return $scope.gridApi.grid.columns[i].getAggregationValue();
}
```

then create a table for the footer when your 'print pdf' btn is clicked

```
 $scope.$on('print', function(event, filter) {
 $scope.gridOptions.exporterPdfFooter = {

        table: {
            widths: [ '*'],

            body: [
                      [ 'Totals: '],

            ]         
        }
    };
$scope.export();
}
```

Comment: You are not using the $scope.$scope.getFooterValue in gridOptions or when making to export(), right? How this will be used then? Also if i is the number of column, how do you pass into the function if this is a dynamic grid where you might have to get aggregate value in multiple columns?